# On hover flip the semi-circle

Tags: html, css

I want to flip the semi-circle on hovering.

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.btm {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 190px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 190px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="height: 100px;">
  </div>
  <div class="btm">
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code the bottom part of the circle is red colored what I want is just **I want to make top part of the circle to be red  on hovering**.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this easily like this using the `linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, red 50%);`. You can swap the colors on hover at the main division.
Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, red 50%);
}

.main:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.btm {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 190px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 190px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.div-1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 190px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-top-right-radius: 190px;
}

.main:hover .div-1 {
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.main:hover .btm {
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div style="height: 100px;" class="div-1">
  </div>
  <div class="btm">
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have added transition effects and used your code! Hope it'll help

Answer (score 1):

you can see this example:

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.btm {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 190px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 190px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .3s;
}
.main:hover .btm {
top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 190px;
  border-top-right-radius: 190px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="height: 100px;">
  </div>
  <div class="btm">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Initially I want the bottom part appear to be red on hovering I want to make the top part red.

Comment: In your answer initially bottom part  is not red

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 190px;
}

.semi-circle {
  position: absolute;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50%;
}

.main:hover .semi-circle {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="semi-circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea relying on `background-clip`

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color:red;
  background-clip:content-box;
  padding:100px 0 0;
}

.main:hover {
  padding: 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>
```

Where you can easily have transition:

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color:red;
  background-clip:content-box;
  padding:100px 0 0;
  transition:1s;
}

.main:hover {
  padding: 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>
```

In case you want a translate animation, here is an idea with gradient:

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) bottom;
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:1s;
}

.main:hover {
  background-position:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is translate your div to the top and also rotate it at the same time to 180 degrees.

For the same there is a CSS attribute `transform: translate(tx, ty) rotate(degrees);`

Here `tx` stands for the pixels, you want to translate on `x-axis`, `ty` stands for the pixels, you want to translate on `y-axis` and `degrees` stands for the degrees that you want to rotate your object.

Your code is the same. I have just added one more CSS class to make it work. Have a look.

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 190px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.btm {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 190px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 190px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.main:hover .btm {
  transform: translate(0, -100px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div style="height: 100px;">
  </div>
  <div class="btm">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.